# Which numerical bonuses could spell perfection double on a toppling quickened magic missile?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat-maneuver, metamagic

When I cast a [toppling magic missile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/toppling-spell-metamagic) and use [spell perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection) to make it quickened as well, what numerical bonuses are there that would be doubled by spell perfection that would help with the CMB roll for toppling?

Improved trip should work, because it is a feat that applies to trip attempts, which is part of a toppling magic missile.

I think feats that increase the CL of magic missile (like [spell specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-specialization)) should be doubled, too before using resulting CL as BAB for the trip, right?

Are there other feats I might be missing?

Comment: Is there a reason why links to archives of nethys are edited to d20pfsrd ones? The latter often do not use the correct names, after all. I know this is because of copyright issues but still it is less reliable for some pieces of information because of that.

Comment: It helps prevent link-rot - 3rd party sites may go down, or be taken down. The idea is to make links that will last for as long as possible and the SRD would generally be considered the 'safest' I think.

Comment: Archives of Nethys has a record of better uptime than d20pfsrd though.

Comment: There is no good reason to change them.  Feel free and revert the links if you want.

Comment: I stand corrected in that case, I used a third-party site in one of my early answers and they were changed to the SRD for this reason.

Comment: (Raw Opinion: I link to *d20PFSRD* because it's easy, well-known, widely used, and *professional*: a dude *makes money* from it. While *Archives* is a fantastic and beautiful resource and what I use for character-building, *Archives* is still an amateur's site--no one *starves* if it's inaccurate (although I've only rarely found it to be so). (The Paizo SRD is too much of a pain to search to link to regularly.))

Comment: @Phlyk the d20pfsrd IS a 3rd party site. The only first-party site is the Paizo PRD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### None.

None of those variables is a set numerical bonus. They are dynamic bonuses.

- *your caster level*, could be 1, 2, 10, etc;
- *your wisdom bonus*, could be +1, +2, +10, etc.

The keywords here are *feats which allow you to apply a set numerical bonus*.

> if you have other **feats which allow you to apply a set numerical bonus** to any aspect of this spell (such as **Spell Focus**, **Spell Penetration**, **Weapon Focus** [ray], and so on), double the bonus granted by that feat when applied to this spell.

That excludes nearly all metamagic feats (those that increase the spell level), that is already covered by the first part of the feat:

> you may apply **any one metamagic feat** you have to that spell without affecting its level or casting time, as long as the total modified level of the spell does not use a spell slot above 9th level.

So, that already covers nearly all metamagics and feats that are a variable bonus.

> I think **feats that increase the CL** of magic missile (like spell specialization) should be doubled, too before using resulting CL as BAB for the trip, right?

If it's not a metamagic, yes.

For instance, these feats would get their bonuses doubled when casting the [Perfected Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection):

- [Combat Casting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/combat-casting---final)
- [Grappled Caster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/grappled-caster)
- [Green Faith Acolyte](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/green-faith-acolyte)
- [Mage's Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/mages-tattoo)
- [Spell Bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-bane)
- [Spiritual Guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spiritual-guardian)
- [Superior Scryer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/superior-scryer)
- [Theurgy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/theurgy)

Comment: The "other feats" clause could still include metamagics, just not the same metamagic that you applied for free.

Comment: @topquark If its a metamagic, it will affect the spell level, meaning that it will not count as the free metamagic from Spell Perfection. Since you cannot apply the same metamagic again, you won't get the benefits twice.

Comment: Say that we Perfect Quicken a Empowered Fireball (3rd -> 5th), that would be a 9th level slot, but since it's perfected, it still uses a 5th level slot. But will not increase the damage by 50% then by another 50%, since the source of this increase is the same feat (empower spell). It's also not a set number.

Comment: Let's pick a metamagic that unambiguously is a "set numerical bonus" (unlike Empower): Tenebrous Spell grants +1 DC and +1 CL; it costs +1 slot-level and some usage restrictions. Say that we Perfect Quicken a Tenebrous Fireball. It takes a 4th-level slot, since the Quicken is free, and Tenebrous is paid for the normal way. Tenebrous is not Perfection's free metamagic, therefore Tenebrous *does* qualify as an "other feat which allows you to apply a set numerical bonus". So Tenebrous's bonus is doubled (which is not the same thing as "applied again"), to +2 DC and +2 CL.

Comment: I believe that if the intent was to stack multiple metamagics, it would list at least one as an example. Metamagics in general cannot be applied to spells without increasing the spell level. By your example, you are trying to apply tenebrous without increasing the spell level. It was increased on the first application, but would need to be increased again on a second application.

Comment: The text on spell perfection says you apply the effects of that feat, but the rules for metamagic says you cannot apply metamagic feats more than once per spell.

Comment: But i could be convinced otherwise, im not 100% sure on this subject.

Comment: I am trying to apply Tenebrous once and only once. I am paying its spell-slot adjustment the normal way, not asking for a discount. And then Spell Perfection doubles the benefit of that single instance of Tenebrous. Just like Spell Perfection's examples (Spell Focus, Spell Penetration, Weapon Focus): If Perfection gave you a 2nd copy of Spell Focus, it wouldn't stack. In order for the doubling clause to do anything ever, it must operate by modifying your single instance of Spell Focus to provide a +2 bonus instead of +1. And that sort of modification is just as applicable to metamagics.

Comment: You are probably right. But i still feel they should have called metamagics on the example. In any case, the exceptions are very limited in this case for it to cause spell perfection to be unbalanced. So i wouldn't mind ruling that it works with tenebrous.